# How to detect keyboard language in Microsoft Teams for Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to get the user's selected keyboard language locale to use from their Microsoft Teams Application.

I am able to get user's selected application language locale through the context object but not the user's keyboard locale.

Is there any way that I can get the user's selected keyboard language locale?

Comment: At present we don't that feature, could you please raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new) for this.

Answer (score 0):

At present we don't have this feature, could you please raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new) for this.